# Prevent Default Link Behavior in Jquery Mobile Listview

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

**Background:**

I'm developing an ecommerce site in jQuery Mobile (JQM). I've created a product page that lists all products in a particular category utilizing JQM's Split Button Listview attribute.

**Here is my working code:**

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-split-icon="plus" data-split-theme="d"         data-theme="d" data-dividertheme="d">
<li data-role="list-divider" class="listdivider">SPI_Level3Entry</li>
<!-- SPI_HTML_Product_Entry1 -->
<li class="prod"><a href="SPI_ProdFullLink" onmouseover="window.status=''; return     true;" rel="SPI_ProdThumbnail"><img src="SPI_ProdThumbnail" alt="SPI_ProdEntryDesc"/>
<!-- SPI_HTML_Product_LinkItemNum -->
<h2>SPI_ProdEntryID</h2>
<!-- SPI_HTML_Product_LinkItemNum -->
<!-- SPI_HTML_Product_Entry_Others -->
<p class="space"><b>
<!-- SPI_HTML_Product_ColHdr_PNs -->
SPI_ColHdrOther</b>
<!-- SPI_HTML_Product_ColHdr_PNs -->
: SPI_ProdEntryOther</p>
<!-- SPI_HTML_Product_Entry_Others -->
<p class="description"><b>Description</b>: SPI_ProdEntryDesc</p>
<!-- SPI_HTML_AllowOrderPlacement -->
<!-- SPI_HTML_AllowViewPriceAvail -->
<p class="space"><b>Qty Avail</b>: SPI_ProdQtyAvail</p>
<p class="space"><b>Unit Price</b>: <span class="price">SPI_ProdEntryPrice</span></p>
<!-- SPI_HTML_AllowViewPriceAvail -->

<input name="SPI_CartProductIDFieldName" type="hidden" value="SPI_ProductID" />
<input name="SPI_CartMfgProdIDFieldName" type="hidden" value="SPI_MfgProdID" />
<input name="SPI_CartProductDescFieldName" type="hidden" value="SPI_ProductDesc" />
<input type="number" name="SPI_CartOrdQtyFieldName" class="nolink" value="0" />

</a>
<a href="#" onClick="javascript:if (document.AddItem.SPI_CartOrdQtyFieldName.value==0)    {document.AddItem.SPI_CartOrdQtyFieldName.value='1'};document.AddItem.submit();">Add</a>
<!-- SPI_HTML_AllowOrderPlacement -->
</li>
</ul>
```

**The Problem**

As you can see, the contents of each li is wrapped in an "a href" attribute. Within the "a href" attribute, I have a text input. The problem is, when I click the text input to enter a value, the default "a href" behavior results.

**The Question**

How do I prevent the default "a href" behavior on the text input in JQM while retaining the default "a href" behavior on the rest of the li content?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can prevent default behavior by calling preventDefault() on the event object.

**example**:

```
$('a').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    //also possible
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
})
```

Comment: Thanks. I wanted to be able to prevent the default link behavior on the text input, but retain it on the rest of the li contents. So, I added a class to the text input and targeted that class to achieve this. That worked. HOWEVER, the "a href's" on all other pages now have their default behavior prevented as well. What gives? Thanks!

Comment: Use a specific selector to target links under this list only. $('#myListId a') or $('#myListId yourClass')